# Webclient Download String returns unexpected results

Tags: c#, webclient

I have this function to download the html code of a website but when i input this particular website it returns a dot(.) instead of the html code, can anyone tell me what wrong or why is it not retuning the code?

Website:"http://bato.to/comic/_/nisekoi-r951"

Code:

```
        public string DownloadString(string add)
        {
            string html = "";            
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Proxy = null;
                client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");                
                while (html=="")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        html = client.DownloadString(add);
                        //MessageBox.Show(html);       
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        html = "";
                    }
                }
                client.Dispose();
            }
            return html;
        }
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does it actually return *null*, or does it throw an exception and therefore get set to the empty string?

Comment: firstly, `httl://` into `http://`

Comment: it returns null because on other website it works.

Comment: Don't say it returns null because on other website it works, say it returns null because it doesn't hit a breakpoint in the catch clause. So does it?

Comment: That is not a valid logic chain. Have you set a breakpoint and verified that `html == null` after `DownloadString` executes, and it **doesn't** hit the catch block?

Comment: well it doesnt return the html code but it returns a dot...

Comment: how are you calling `DownloadString` ? What's the value of add in your code ?

Comment: If it doesn't throw an exception and it returns a non empty string, you should be breaking the loop and getting that result. Whether it is valid html or not is a different issue.

Comment: A dot is neither null nor empty string. Please [edit] your question and quote exactly what output you get.

Comment: @Florian add has the value of the web url.

Comment: Also rename any `add` variable you have to `url` or at least `address`. Short is good, but readable and understandable - more.

Comment: @Yorye it doesnt return the html like other websites do.

Comment: Still doesn't return `null`. Your question requires fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "https" on that site:

```
 public static string DownloadString(string add)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
                return client.DownloadString(add);
            }
        }
```

The calling code:

```
Console.WriteLine(DownloadString("https://bato.to/comic/_/nisekoi-r951"));
```

Sample response:

```
               <div class='ipbfs_login_col'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='inline_invisible' name='anonymous
' value='1' class='input_check left' />
                    <div style='padding-left: 20px;'>
                        <label for='inline_invisible'>
                            <strong>Sign in anonymously</strong>
                            <span class='desc lighter' style='display: block; pa
dding-top: 5px;'>Don't add me to the active users list</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```